# AWS RDS MySQL Bin Change Log

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Yesterday, our MySQL instance running on Amazon RDS hung and we were forced to reboot. After rebooting we noticed additional rows in one of our tables that were not there before the crash.

The rows were originally "supposed" to be written to this table via a trigger when updates occurred on another table. This was an "Audit Log" table. There is a datetime column on the "Audit Log" table that indicated when the row was originally "supposed" to be written. These dates stretch up to 3 years ago! About 7,000 rows were added after rebooting! The trigger generates a date value when the row was actually written to the "Audit Log" table and that had yesterday's date!

The RDS MySQL log had this snippet in it during reboot.

```
InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 181143261075
150922 17:07:44  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 181143275223
150922 17:07:51  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 40603, file name /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog.268331
150922 17:07:51  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150922 17:07:52 InnoDB: 5.5.40 started; log sequence number 181143275223
150922 17:07:52 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog
150922 17:07:52 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
150922 17:07:52 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
```

Clearly MySQL re-applied these "updates" because of the crash. My questions are the following:

- How in the world would this innoDB bin transaction log have records that should have been written years ago?
- If the trigger failed for these rows the update SQL statement would have failed, correct? Our code is configured to then rollback the transaction.

I'm my no means a DBA, and these might be dump questions but I was just extremely confused to have such old records appear!

MySQL 5.5.40. InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

While it is remotely possible that crash recovery with prior data corruption could result in unexpected data reappearing, what you describe seems unlikely to have happened the way it appears to have happened.

It is almost unthinkable that the date values could be current values, in such a case. No mechanism comes to mind that even *could* do that, since the trigger and the clock run at one layer of the server, and crash recovery is at a very different one.

It seems more likely that somebody did something to the server that they are not admitting... a wayward query or application bug or improper playback of a backup file... that last possibility would even explain why you thought the server "hung."  When you load a backup file generated by `mysqldump` using the default configuration, it locks each table as the new data is being loaded.

If you still have access to the binary logs (unlikely, since RDS purges them pretty quickly unless you've configured it not to) then could potentially learn more about what happened.

Another approach I would try if it were me would be to do a point in time recovery from right before the disruption, yesterday.  This creates a new instance (it doesn't disrupt the existing one).  From that snapshot, it might be interesting to inspect the contents of the tables in question and verify that they contain what you expected at the time.